# python Elastic search BadRequestError while making insensitive match analyzer

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build an index that is searchable for a possible case insensitive exact match. The Elasticsearch version is 8.6.2 with Lucene version is 9.4.2. The code is run in Python with Python's elasticsearch library.

```
settings = {"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {"lower_analizer": {"tokenizer": "whitespace", "filter": [ "lowercase" ]} }
    }
  }
}

mappings = {"properties": {
                "title": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
                "article": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "lower_analizer"},
                "sentence_id": {"type": "integer"},
    }
}
```

I copied the settings from [Elasticsearch's tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). However, it returned the following error:

```
BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 
'unknown setting [index.settings.analysis.analyzer.lower_analizer.filter]
 please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the
 breaking changes documentation for removed settings')
```

I'm not sure where to proceed, as it implies lowercase function does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) analyzer there is lowercase filter in default.

Text field types uses standard analyzer

[image]

```
PUT test_stackoverflow/_doc/1
{
  "text": "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
}

GET test_stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "quick"
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_stackoverflow",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "text": "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Result as image:
[image]